# count values of checked checkbox

Tags: jquery

I want to get the total value of all checked checkboxes. What i've tried is this:

```
$("input[type=checkbox]:checked").each(function() {
            total_modules += parseFloat($(this).val());
        });
        $("#total_modules").text(total_modules.toFixed(2));
```

This didn't work.

I hope someone can help me.

Thanks in advance!

PS: I fixed it, this is my new code:

```
function calculation()
    {
    $("input[type=checkbox]:checked").each(function() {
            total_modules += parseFloat($(this).val());
        });
        $("#total_modules").text(total_modules.toFixed(2)); 
    }
    calculation();

    $("input[type=checkbox]").click(function()
    {
        calculation();
    });
```

Thank you all

Comment: Instead of using `$(this).val()` you can use the native code `this.value'.

Answer (score 0):

You can do `$("input[type=checkbox]:checked").length` to get the number of checked checkboxes.

Check out this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/V4bes/)

Answer (score 0):

its very simple use

```
 $("input[type=checkbox]:checked").length;
```

refer http://www.codeunit.co.za/2010/08/18/jquery-count-number-of-checkboxes-checked-on-a-page/

Comment: Thanks but i don't need the number of checkboxes but the total of the checkbox values.

Comment: alert($("input[type=checkbox]:checked").length); will give you the number of tick marked checkboxes

Answer (score 0):

use the length property

```
var checkcount = $(":checkbox:checked").length;
```

Answer (score 0):

The below code should work with jQuery version 1.7.1

JQUERY

```
$("#test").click(function() {
var tot = 0;
    $.each($("input[type=checkbox]:checked"), function (k, v){
    var val =parseFloat($(this).val());
    tot = parseFloat(tot + val);   
    })
        alert(tot);
});
```

HTML

```
<input type="checkbox" value ="10.2"/>
<input type="checkbox" value ="10.2"/>
<input type="checkbox" value ="10.2"/>
<input type="checkbox" value ="10.2"/>

<input type="buttoN" id="test" value="click me"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like

```
$(function(){
    var checkboxes = $("input:checkbox");
    checkboxes.change(function(){
        var total = 0.0;

        checkboxes.filter(":checked").each(function(){
            total += parseFloat(this.value);
        });

        alert (total)
    });
});
```

See a [***working demo***](http://jsfiddle.net/7zxJh/)

Answer (score -1):

Could it be that the decimal separator is incorrect? I think it needs to be a . for parseFloat to work correctly.

You also need to check if the parsed value is a number with

```
isNaN(parsedValue)
```