# How can I get values from checkbox and count clicked items with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to get values for each checkbox and break movement to another page if the user doesn't check any box.

there is an error but I cant recognize it

```
$('#Submit').click( function() {

        if($('#Search').val() == "")
        {alert('please enter your domain without Extuntison');return false;}

        results.style.display = 'none';
        $('#results').html('');
        loading.style.display = 'inline';

        $.post('../domain_checker/process.php?domain=' + escape($('#Search').val()),{
        }, function(response){


            results.style.display = 'block';
            $('#results').html(unescape(response)); 
            loading.style.display = 'none';

            //$('#results').animate({height : '450px' }, 2000);

            results.style.height = '400px';
        });

        return false;
    });


       $(function(){
          $('#order_Now').click(function(){
             var count = $("[type='checkbox']:checked").length;
             var val = [];
             for(i=0;i<count;i++){
                $(':checkbox:checked').each(function(i){
                   val[i] = $(this).val();
                });
             }      
          });
       });
```

and this html page when load ajax

```
 <form action="ordedomain.php" name="formdomain" method="post" id="formdomain"  onclick="check_domain_checkBox()">

     <div id="results" style="width:450px;" align="left">



     </div> 
     </form>
```

and this  code reloade by ajax in page php

```
       <form action="ordedomain.php" name="formdomain" method="post" id="formdomain"  onclick="check_domain_checkBox()">

<input type="checkbox" value="a" id="arrDomain" name="arrDomain">a
<input type="checkbox" value="b" id="arrDomain" name="arrDomain">b
<input type="checkbox" value="c" id="arrDomain" name="arrDomain">c

        </form>
```

Comment: i send checked item to anther page but i need to check if didn't check any of this before submit also this checkbox reloaded by Ajax , because i created code by Ajax
so this checkbox are dynamic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's simple:

```
var vals = [];
$(":checkbox").each(function() {
    if (this.checked)
       vals.push(this.value);
});
var count = vals.length;
```

I'm not sure what the `for`-loop is doing in your code as you already have the `each()`.

Now you can easily get the count in your `submit` handler, if it equals `0` prevent the submit.

Also, you shouldn't use submit buttons if you want checkboxes; and you can't use an `id` multiple times (it needs to be unique), use the `name` attribute instead:

```
<form action="ordedomain.php" name="formdomain" method="post" id="formdomain">
  <label><input type="checkbox" name="domain" value="1"> Order now 1</label>
  <label><input type="checkbox" name="domain" value="2"> Order now 2</label>
  <label><input type="checkbox" name="domain" value="3"> Order now 3</label>
  <label><input type="checkbox" name="domain" value="4"> Order now 5</label>
  <input type="text" id="search" name="search">
  <div id="results" style="display:none;"></div>
  <img id="loading" src="…" style="display:none;"></div>
</form>
```

```
// onDOMready
var form = $("#formdomain"),
    search = form.find("#search"),
    checkboxes = form.find(":checkbox"),
    results = form.find("#results"),
    loading = form.find("#loading");
form.submit(function(evt) {
    var sval = search.val(),
        checked = checkboxes.filter(":checked"),
        dvals = [];
    if (!sval) {
        alert("Please enter domain (without extension)");
    } else if (!checked.length) {
        alert("Please tick at least one domain extension");
    } else {
        checked.each(function() {
            dvals.push(this.value);
        });
        $.post('../domain_checker/process.php', {
            domain: sval,
            extensions: dvals
        }, function(resonse) {
            loading.hide();
            results.html(response).show();
        });
        loading.show();
        results.hide();
    }
    evt.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: i send checked item to anther page but 
i need to check if didn't check any of this before submit 
also this checkbox reloaded by Ajax , because  i created code by Ajax

Comment: Please show us the code for this ajax thing and also the checkboxes in your question

Comment: I guess you want this (see extended answer), if not please show me the *entire* form. If those checkboxes are loaded dynamically (into a different form?) you should use delegated events

Answer (score 1):

try these (correct code)

```
 var count = $("input[type='checkbox']:checked").length;
```

and

```
  $("input[type='checkbox']:checked").each(function(i){
```

read http://api.jquery.com/checked-selector/

Answer (score 0):

you can get by `.is(':checked')`

and get checked by

jquery

```
$("#test").click(function() {
var total_c = 0;
    $.each($("input[type=checkbox]:checked"), function (k, v){
    var val =parseFloat($(this).val());
    tot = parseFloat(total_c+ val);   
    })
        alert(total_c);
});
```

html

```
<input type="buttoN" id="test" value="click me"/>
```

**Good Learn**

1. [jquery checkbox value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4813219/jquery-checkbox-value)
2. [count values of checked checkbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8502089/count-values-of-checked-checkbox)

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any checkboxes in the html you provided and also all the 4 **submit buttons have the same ID value** which is wrong. This might be the reason why it is not working. Also you can modify your js code to get correct count for checked checkboxes

```
var vals = [];
$(":checkbox:checked").each(function() {
       vals.push($(this).val());
});
```